# How to change the nav bar color when it reaches the next div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Is there a way to for the header to change color when it reaches the next div? I am trying to have it where the nav bar color changes when scrolling to the next div "container"

[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-lake-hb1nh?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like @neaumusic has already answered, adding a scroll event listener can help.

Here is a working code I wrote: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/responsive-colored-header-t8jxr)

What I like to do is separating the event listener to a custom hook.

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef, RefObject } from "react";

interface ITopBottom {
  top: number;
  bottom: number;
}

const useElementLocation = <T extends HTMLElement>(): [
  RefObject<T>,
  ITopBottom
] => {
  // ref object to return
  const ref = useRef<T>(null);

  // you can customize this to include width, height, etc.
  const [loc, setLoc] = useState<ITopBottom>({ top: 0, bottom: 0 });

  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = () => {


      const rect = ref.current?.getBoundingClientRect()
      if(rect){

        setLoc({
          top:rect.top,
          bottom: rect.bottom,
        })
      }
    };

    // add the listener as the component mounts
    window.addEventListener("scroll",listener)

    // guarantee the listener is executed at least once
    listener();

    // clean up
    return ()=>window.removeEventListener("scroll",listener)
  }, []);
  return [ref,loc]
};

export default useElementLocation;
```

This hook returns a ref object to be placed in the div, and the corresponding position you need.

Now you know the bounding top and bottom position, use logical statements to determine whether the header has reached a target div, and change the color depending on the result.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import useElementLocation from "./useElementLocation"

export default () => {
  const [headerRef, headerLoc] = useElementLocation<HTMLDivElement>();
  const [divRef, divLoc] = useElementLocation<HTMLDivElement>();

  const [headerColor, setHeaderColor] = useState("white"); // default color

  useEffect(()=>{
    const {bottom: headerBottom} = headerLoc;
    const {top,bottom} = divLoc;
    if(top<headerBottom && headerBottom<bottom){
      // header has reached the div
      setHeaderColor("black");
    } else {
      // header has left the div, either to the higher or lower
      setHeaderColor("white");
    }
  },[divLoc, headerLoc]) //dependencies

  return <div className="app">
    <div className="header" style={{backgroundColor: headerColor}} ref={headerRef}></header>
    <div className="div-to-watch" ref={divRef}></div>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: im not familar with typescript yet

Comment: I made the same app also in javascript. You can check it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/responsive-colored-header-js-yhco4?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
container.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
  if (container.scrollTop > someChildElement.offsetTop) {
    changeColor(navbar);
  }
});
```